# How to fix size of text in UITextField so it should not overlap the label?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitextfield, uilabel

I've a `UITextField` and a `UILabel` on it. The label is right aligned and the text is left aligned, the problem is that when i enter text in text field, whenever the size of text goes bigger it overlap the label.
How can i prevent the label to be overlapped?

Comment: Make the UITextField narrower?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, but i can't do this because i've label inside the text field and it should not be disappeared when user enter text and also not overlapped, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated:-you can use table view cell of type value1 or value2 that gives you this format and Used TextLabel as main heading and place the textfield in place of detailtext.That can be fix.

Comment: yes i know about placeholder, but i need a label that should not removed when user enter text, [I'm looking like some thing like this image](http://www.carettasoftware.com/gallery/images/IPC_ContactInfo_Stage2.png)

Comment: you want like title work ,home and all in blue textcolor rite?

Comment: Exactly, but textcolor is not an issue.

Comment: I accepted your answer and upvote it, means it solved my problem. Thanks