# UILabel and UITextField overlapping in the same cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In one `UITableViewCell` I have `UILabel` and `UITextField` like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsawF.png]

As you can see the `UITextField` is aligned to the right. After I write something in the text field it overlaps.

How can I avoid this?

And this code snippets are how to fill cell

```
cell.textLabel.text = R_NAME_CLIENT_NAME;
        self->clientNameLabel = cell.textLabel;
       [self createTextField:&clientName WithDefaultText:@"none" WithText:@"" InCell:cell IndexPath:indexPath];

- (void) createTextField:(UITextField**)textField WithDefaultText:(NSString*)defaultText WithText:(NSString*)text InCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell IndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
*textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 11, cell.frame.size.width - 20, 20)];
(*textField).font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-ItalicMT" size:17];
```

}

[Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213435/how-to-fix-size-of-text-in-uitextfield-so-it-should-not-overlap-the-label) did **not** help me.

Comment: In the storyboard you can define the size of your components so they don't overlap, did you do it?

Comment: Thanks but i did not use storyboard I m trying to do it programatically

Comment: So you could define their frames. The first answer should help.

Comment: It did not worked for me and I added som code snippets to my question

Answer (score 0):

Give a correct frames to both elements:

```
CGFloat width = 100;
CGFloat height = 25;
myLabel.frame = CGRectMake (0,0, width, height);
CGFloat labelEndX = myLabel.frame.origin.x + myLabel.frame.size.width;
myTextField.frame = CGRectMake(labelEndX , 0, cell.contentView.size.width - labelEndX, height);
```

Comment: sorry did not helped me again I edited my question with code snippets

Comment: But from the code i see that you start your textfield from x==10: [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 11, cell.frame.size.width - 20, 20)]; You have to start it from where label ends: label.origin.x + label.size.width.